# how to get a parameter from a runbook when it is excuted through logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to fetch parameter from the Run Book when it trigger via azure logic apps

```
get job output(Azure Automation)

azure run book (Power Shell)

$Name="Client-A"
echo $Name
```

is there and method to get this parameter as i need to send this value over mail
example: trigger body, output from the #content

Comment: So your logic app will use webhook to trigger your azure runbook with some dynamic params and you want to get these params in logic app following steps ?

Comment: right now it is just scheduler(recurrence), yes Stanley

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the parameters you pass to the runbook, you could get it with the expression like `body('Create_job')['properties']['parameters']['parametername']`. The result would be like below picture shows. In my test I get all parameters.

[image]

And if you want to get the parameter you set in the runbook like `$Name="Client-A"`, for now logic app doesn't support to get it. However if you change the default parameter you set in the runbook with logic app, you still could get it.